# How to depict an image in canvas using segment anything result data

Tags: pytorch, sam

In the example below, I get the generated data. I want to pass this `masks` to the web client to draw the mask image in the canvas, but I don't know which data inside the `masks` can be used to draw the image.
Can you give me an example?

```
from segment_anything import SamAutomaticMaskGenerator, sam_model_registry
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
sam = sam_model_registry["vit_b"] (checkpoint="/Users/jiangxingshang/Downloads/sam_vit_b_01ec64.pth")
sam.to(device='cuda')
mask_generator = SamAutomaticMaskGenerator(sam)

img = Image.open("/Users/jiangxingshang/Pictures/8435e5dde71190ef699eced5cc1b9d16fdfa6056.jpg")
imgnp = np.array(img)
masks = mask_generator.generate(imgnp)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this [example](https://github.com/facebookresearch/segment-anything/blob/main/notebooks/automatic_mask_generator_example.ipynb).

Briefly, `masks` is a list, in which each mask is a dictionary.
For example,

```
first_mask = masks[0]['segmentation']
```

will assign the first mask to `first_mask` variable, assuming the list `masks` is not empty.

The dictionary keys are the following:

- segmentation : the mask
- area : the area of the mask in pixels
- bbox : the boundary box of the mask in XYWH format
- predicted_iou : the model's own prediction for the quality of the mask
- point_coords : the sampled input point that generated this mask
- stability_score : an additional measure of mask quality
- crop_box : the crop of the image used to generate this mask in XYWH format